# Trying to get RESTful in MVC (.NET f/x 4.5.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have the following piece of code in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Clone/{sessionId:int}")]
public ActionResult CloneContinue(int sessionId)
{
    // Resume a saved Work Session...
    var response = GetCachedCurrentWorkSession(sessionId);

    if (response.Status >= (int) SessionStatuses.Started)
    {
        // ---==[ BELOW THIS IS FAILING ]==---
        return RedirectToAction("Assembly", "ProductReuse", new { sessionId = response.SessionId });  // <<<=== THIS IS FAILING ===<<<
        // ---==[ ABOVE THIS IS FAILING ]==---
    }
    return View("Clone", response);
}
```

When it executes, it is sending it to:
http://localhost/My.Web/ProductReuse/Assembly?sessionId=50

I expected:
http://localhost/My.Web/ProductReuse/Assembly/50.

Any ideas why it is doing this?

The action I am redirecting to:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Assembly/{sessionId:int}/{showResults:bool?}")]
public ActionResult Assembly(int sessionId, bool showResults = false)
{
    var response = GetCachedCurrentWorkSession(sessionId);
    response.ShowResults = showResults;
    return View(response);
}
```

My RouteConfig.cs looks like:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!

Changed the `return RedirectToAction(...)` to:

```
return RedirectToRoute("GetAssembly", new {userWorkSessionId = response.UserWorkSessionId});
```